# Java remote data synchronization

Tags: java, data-structures, synchronization

I am looking for an API which can synchronize some sort of DataStore object between multiple remote ends (via network). For example a master (server) data store would synchronize its content (attributes annotated in such a way) to all connected remote ends (slaves/clients). The slaves or clients, depending on the way you look at it, would then only have reading access to all objects in the data store.

This would greatly simplify distribution of objects across multiple peers. Now I am sure that I am not the first soul to think of something like this, but I cannot for the life of me, find such an API. I have been looking for it for a while now and even started my own implementation out of frustration, though I am uncertain, if this will bear fruits.
Google will give me a lot of RMI, Thread-synchronization and Database synchronization stuff, which is **not** what I need. I need this DETACHED from any kind of database and I do not want to work it through some sort of RMI.
Has anyone ever used such an API and can tell me where to find it?

Comment: So where do you store data? Memory? File system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.org/) which is perhaps one of the simplest to do this.

Also have a look at their [hazelcast.com](http://www.hazelcast.com/)

Comment: On first looks, this is exactly what I am looking for. I will take a closer look and probably mark this as the right answer within an hour or so.